# Unable to directly Edit html in the browser in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-editor-web-part, html-editor

From yesterday onwards, am Unable to directly Edit html in the browser in SharePoint Online env.
i have created a folder called htmfiles in my siteassets librray on my SPO site, and i have a html file that has css, js, and html content.

When i tried to edit the html file, am getting a message, " its just a preview".

[image: unabel2edit]

Is this a change from MSFT side? did they announce these changes in advance?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Something seems to be very wrong on the Microsoft end. It is more than you think because I also can no longer change the html file a web part references or make a new web part to display an HTML file.

The good news is that you can still edit the current HTML files with the content editor. The only reason I know the answer is because I still had an HTML file open in content editor, otherwise there is no way you would figure this out.

When you get to that annoying broken link page you arrived to add the following text to the end of the URL:

**&p=5**

It will take you directly to the code and have it open in the text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Have you test using another user? Does this issue happen on all files?

You can try to upload a new html file and check the results.

Also test in other browser or other machine.

Comment: hi Allen, its not working for the browsers - IE11 and GOOGLE CHROME browsers. and i have tested with my team members' machines as well. They too face the same issue. Also, my customer tried to do the same and came back to us, why this is happening! Didnt understand the reason for removing the useful feature. We could have directly updated the html, css, js code using this userfriendly feature

Comment: I did not find such an official article talking about removing this feature. I would suggest you submit a service request in the O365 admin center > Support > New service request for more professional help.